# Changing button behavior after countdown in Android

Tags: android, button, onclick, countdowntimer

I have a small game application, where the user guesses the sum of two numbers randomly generated by the app. He has 10 seconds to enter the answer (a Countdown Timer is used for this). When he enters the number and clicks the "Confirm" button, the OnClick method checks if he was correct, displays the toast "Right" or "Wrong", and then the activity is restarted. He then has another two numbers to guess the sum of, and it goes on for 10 times.

(I used the Intent for restarting the activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent (This application.this, This application.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

After 10 rounds, the game goes to the next activity and displays the total result (I have a counter for that in the next activity, it increments whenever the user enters the correct sum). Now, the rule states that if the 10 seconds for guessing the number are up, the answer should automatically qualify as wrong even if the user enters the correct number and clicks the button. This means that the toast "You haven't entered any answer" is displayed, and the counter in the next activity is not incremented (after that the activity restarts and the game continues normally). I have everything else set up properly, but I don't know how to pull this off. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be much grateful...

Comment: simply make timer and make flag for trueAnswer, if its true then answer is right else wong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your countdown include a `boolean` flag that lets you check whether the countdown is still running. Something like:

```
boolean CountdownRunning = false;
GameCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    // While the countdown is ticking set flag to true 
    CountdownRunning = true;
}

public void onFinish() {
    // When the countdown finishes set flag back to false 
    CountdownRunning= false;
}
}.start();
```

Then in your OnClick method I'm guessing you have an 'if' statement that handles whether the answer is right or wrong. Add a second condition to the correct answer statement that checks whether the countdown is still running.

```
if(CorrectAnswer && CountdownRunning)
```

The second condition should mean that your counter only increments if the answer is within the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, David! It's working perfectly :)